# Rearrangement of site toolbar

Tags: discussion, support

I just noticed that the site toolbar has been rearranged (I am tempted to say "scrambled", but I don't want to be rude :). I strongly prefer the old arrangement and would like to see it restored. What can I do to make my preference for the old one known to the powers-that-be.

Comment: It is possible to post feedback as an answer to the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live?cb=1). Upvoting criticism one agrees with also seems like a good idea.

Comment: And it's been [discussed for around a month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network) and "Featured on Meta," and SO had a similar change about half a year ago or so.

Comment: I have not tested this, so I'm not posting as an answer, but have a look here. https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices (ofc this does not answer your question, but does help restore the old arrangement)